# Disable charging sound on iPhone

Tags: iphone, charging, charger

I'm using an iPhone SE with iOS 14.42. When plugging a charging cable into the phone, it makes a notification sound if the Silent Mode is off. The phone makes no sound if the Silent Mode is on.

How can I stop the sound from playing the notification sound when Silent Mode is off?

So far, I have tried the app "Silent Plug", which works as long as the app runs. I also tried using the "Shortcuts" app to create a shortcut that plays a silent .mp3 when plugging in the cable, but that has no effect.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is turning down `Ringer and Alerts` down to silent in `Volume` settings, but it would also silence all your calls as if its on silent mode (but technically it's not on silent mode, based on the physical switch on the side of your phone). I'm not sure if that would also affect app notification sounds, as I usually have my app notification sounds off and my phone is always on silent mode.

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason why you need the charge sound off? Is the charging sound **repeatedly** going off when plugged into a Mac by any chance? If so, it may be an unstable power supply between the Mac and the iPhone when connected over the Apple USB-A lightning cable, which I've reported on this forum before here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382002/iphone-mac-connection-issue-and-what-does-the-usbd-process-do If this is the reason, I suggest you read my post as it provides some detail and how to temporarily fix the unstable supply (albeit at a lower power current)

Comment: @AVelj You suggested "turning down Ringer and Alerts down to silent in Volume settings". This does not disable the notification sound when plugging in the charging cable. Also I can say that the problem is not caused by an "unstable power supply between the Mac and the iPhone", because I am not plugging in my iPhone into a Mac, but into a wall charger.

Comment: @AVelj For your question "Also, is there a particular reason why you need the charge sound off?" The main reason is that there is an unstable connection between iPhone and charging wire and the charging sound is going off repeatedly when plugged into my wall charger. I have had this fixed two times in them past which brings relief for 6-12 months. Apart from that, the charging sound annoys me anyway and I would like to get rid of it. The "Silent" switch on my iPhone switches between silenced and not silenced several times per second when in the silent position, so cannot be used in this case.