# Unable to charge iPad Pro 2018 from MacBook Pro

Tags: ipad, usb, charging

I have been connecting my iPad Pro to my MacBook Pro for years to enable sidecar and at the same time charge it. Suddenly it will not charge anymore. Not sure if it happened after an upgrade to either iOS og macOS. Charging the iPad using a power adapter works fine.

I also have a one-year old iPad Air that is charging without problems from the usb-c port on the Mac using the same cable.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue or if there is anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Even if the iPad Air charges without problems: can you try a different cable?

Comment: I have tried two different cables and two different Macs

Comment: Same issue here. MacBook Air (M1, 2020) -> iPad Pro 12.9 (3d gen). Charges for a few seconds, then stops.

Comment: It may be related to a similar problem I have described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382002/iphone-mac-connection-issue-and-what-does-the-usbd-process-do The only thing I could suggest is try killing usbd (which is used to configure iOS devices connected to a Mac). To kill the usbd process, go into terminal and enter `sudo killall -STOP -c usbd`, it'll prompt you to enter your Mac's password (but it won't appear as you type it). Killing the process, reduces the power current the Mac provides to the iPad, so it'll charge significantly slower, but provide a stable connection.

Comment: For some reason the problem fixed itself for me. I think it happened after upgrading the iPad to new version of iOS.