USB Devices Frequently Disconnect/Reconnect After macOS Sonoma 14.5 Update
I recently updated my MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) to macOS `Sonoma 14.5 (23F79). Since the update, I've been experiencing frequent disconnects and reconnects of my USB devices. This issue is particularly problematic because it disrupts my ability to use my iPad with Sidecar.
Here are the specs of my MacBook Pro:

Processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7

Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4

macOS: Sonoma 14.5


Has anyone else encountered this issue, or does anyone have suggestions for resolving it? I've tried basic troubleshooting steps like rebooting my system and reconnecting the USB devices, but the problem persists.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm unsure about your situation (since you MacBook uses USB C/Thunderbolt 3 ports) but you may want to see my own question regarding USB A connection issues between Macs and iOS devices. This workaround may also work for USB C/Thunderbolt 3 (but I can't confirm it since I'm on an older 2013 MacBook Pro). However there is no harm in trying the workaround. See here:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382002/iphone-mac-connection-issue-and-what-does-the-usbd-process-do

it was fixed by downloading new updates
